# UITableview tablecell separator missing when the tablecell is selected programatically

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, ios7.1

```
@implementation TestTableViewCell

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if(highlighted || self.selected)
    {
        self.labelTest.tintColor = self.tintColor;
        self.labelTest.text = @"HighLighted";
    }
    else
    {
        self.labelTest.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.labelTest.text = @"Not HighLighted";
    }


}


@end

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];

    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO    scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

This is my code. If the row is 5 programmatically select the cell using *selectRowAtIndexPath*. When I do this, the tableseperator is missing in 7.1 But the same code works fine in 7.0

[image: ios 7.0]    [image: ios 7.1]

Not sure why the separator is missing in 7.1

Comment: This sounds similar to this question. It sounds like the cell is drawing on top of the separator. You could try adjusting the height of the cell.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358831/ios-7-1-uitableviewcell-content-overlaps-with-ones-below

Comment: @DaveS I tried that before posting the question. Unfortunately that did not work for me. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init]; also looks suspicious to me. Why are you using a blank view for the background when selected? From your pictures it looks unnecessary and if the separator is in the background view it would explain missing separator.

Comment: the problem is the view is overlaying the separator just make sure you are returning the proper height for heightForRowAtIndexPath method and make sure you aren't changing view heights during runtime

Comment: I am using custom uitableviewcell. I am not changing the height dynamically.

Comment: Calling `selectRowAtIndex` _inside_ `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is wrong. At that moment cell doesn't exist yet. Try to move `selectRowAtIndex` outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was setting the selectedbackground. It works fine in iOS7 but have some issues in 7.1